# Testing not known module in unittest with Python 3

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, python-import

I observe a strange behaviour with Python 3 unittest. Following Testcase tests in function `testValue` a module that does not exist.

```
import sys
import unittest

class ModuleTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def testValue(self):
        import unknown_module
        result = unknown_module.value

        self.assertEqual(0.0, result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sys.version)
    unittest.main()
```

Python2 gives correctly following output:

```
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
E
======================================================================
ERROR: testValue (__main__.ModuleTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\bin\WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.1\workspace\unknown_module_test.py", line 7, in testValue
    import unknown_module
ImportError: No module named unknown_module

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

But Python 3 claims an AttributeError when the `unknown_module.value` is referenced.

```
3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:55:48) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
E
======================================================================
ERROR: testValue (__main__.ModuleTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unknown_module_test.py", line 8, in testValue
    result = unknown_module.value
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'value'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.016s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Why doesn't throw Python 3 an `ImportError` as Python 2 does?

Comment: No, can't reproduce this. I just get an `ImportError`. What is the *real* name of your unknown module? Are you 100% certain that you didn't find a module added to Python 3 you did not know about? What does `print(unknown_module.__file__)` tell you was imported?

Comment: I think the module `unknown_module` exists somewhere in Python 3.3 module search path. (not in Python 2.7 module path).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters : It gives the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'`.

Comment: @Holger: but there *is* a module object? Sounds like a built-in module in that case. What does `print(unknown_module.__name__)` give? Or better still, give us `print(dir(unknown_module))`.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters : It gives `unknown_module` and
`['__doc__', '__initializing__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']` on the module search path. I found out that I have an empty directory `unknown_module`, but there is no file `__init__.py` in it. But this is still mandatory to declare a package in `Python 3`, isn't it?

Comment: @Holger: no, it is not. Namespaces can now be empty directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are importing an *implicit namespace* package. Quoting from the [Python 3.3 What's New page](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-420-implicit-namespace-packages):

> Native support for package directories that don’t require __init__.py marker files and can automatically span multiple path segments (inspired by various third party approaches to namespace packages, as described in PEP 420)

and [PEP 420 Implicit Namespace Packages](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/):

> If the scan completes without returning a module or package, and at least one directory was recorded, then a namespace package is created. The new namespace package:
>
> - Has a `__path__` attribute set to an iterable of the path strings that were found and recorded during the scan.
> - Does not have a `__file__` attribute.

and

> Namespace packages and regular packages are very similar. The differences are:
>
> - Portions of namespace packages need not all come from the same directory structure, or even from the same loader. Regular packages are self-contained: all parts live in the same directory hierarchy.
> - Namespace packages have no `__file__` attribute.
> - Namespace packages' `__path__` attribute is a read-only iterable of strings, which is automatically updated when the parent path is modified.
> - Namespace packages have no `__init__.py` module.
> - Namespace packages have a different type of object for their `__loader__` attribute.

Remove the `unknown_module` directory from your `sys.path` and your test will fail the way it did in earlier Python versions.

Comment: Ok, that's new in 3.3. But, isn't that in contradiction to what is written below [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages). There it is written _The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages_. I relied on that.

Comment: It doesn't quite contradict the new namespace feature (you still need a `__init__.py` if the directory is *not* a namespace package, e.g. it contains actual modules). Yet the tutorial could do with some updating there.